# "Resource temporarily unavailable" starting service inside docker

Tags: docker, resources, ulimit

It seems I'm running into some limit, but not sure which. I raised the number of files (`ulimit -n`) and processes (`ulimit -u`) in the host machine, without success.

This only happens when I manually restart the service with `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart` after it has been running for some time (it usually crashes for out of memory error). The first time it runs fine. Elasticsearch needs to lock some memory before starting (inside the docker).

Here's the strace. I can't really figure out what's happening:

```
...
write(1, "Starting elasticsearch: ", 24Starting elasticsearch: ) = 24
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1f4bae2a10) = 3268
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x4413f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, {sa_handler=0x4413f0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, 8) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 128)                        = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=3268, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 3268
wait4(-1, 0x7fff5904a290, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x43e860, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, {sa_handler=0x43e860, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "", R_OK)           = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=4, ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid", R_OK) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
open("/var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid", O_RDONLY) = 3
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(0, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fff5904a690)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(0, "2429", 128)                    = 4
read(0, "", 128)                        = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
stat("/proc/2429", 0x7fff5904a610)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fff5904a690)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 4
read(0, "", 128)                        = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/sbin/runuser", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=32984, ...}) = 0
stat("/sbin/runuser", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=32984, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/sbin/runuser", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/sbin/runuser", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=32984, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/sbin/runuser", R_OK)           = 0
stat("/sbin/runuser", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=32984, ...}) = 0
stat("/sbin/runuser", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=32984, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/sbin/runuser", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/sbin/runuser", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=32984, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/sbin/runuser", R_OK)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [INT CHLD], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f1f4bae2a10) = 3270
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x43e860, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f1f4b1033b0}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, runuser: failed to execute /bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable
...
```

Comment: After some move investigation, this seems to be due to exhaust the number of available processes (ulimit -u). Still at a loss why processes are not freed after the crash (and when no other process seems to be running inside the docker).